# Word/Phrase for when you don't want something

Tags: word-choice

Like if you were to tell someone that they had inherited a title or something like that and they didn't want it at all. Like they hated the idea of it.

The closest I've found is reticent but that's more about concealing true feelings, whereas I'm wanting it to be like profusely denying the thing being given.

Comment: Did he abdicate ?

Comment: They can *politely turn it down* or they can *flatly refuse it.*

Answer (score 4):

"abnegate" means to give up rights or a claim.

> - [**abnegate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abnegate) - "renounce or reject" (something desired or valuable)

- "The young man decided to abnegate all mundane pleasures."
- "Queen Matilda abnegated her Anglo-Saxon descent."

Comment: Excellent - never heard of that!